# Fineuploader set ACL public-read

Tags: fine-uploader

My upload script is working fine other than I try to set acl to public-read

objectProperties: {
        acl: "public-read",
        other properties
     },

I get access denied when uploading. If I remove this or change to acl: "private" it works.

i think it's got to do with S3 CORS or maybe headers being sent, could you please set me straight.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, sorry my bad. IAM user did not have putobject-acl provisioned